# Get filePath for Recents,Downloads,Images from Uri of ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery, android-11

I am invoking image picker in my android app using intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT.
In onActivityResult() I get Uri using data.getData().

Now I am using an already existing code to compress this image but that requires filePath to the image.

I am getting null while parsing path from Uri for Recents, Downloads, Images.

I use projection MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA on contentResolver.query() with Uri. It fetched correct filePath for all other options except Recents, Downloads, Images.

How can I make these work ? The solution should work on latest Android version.

Uris not working:

Downloads- content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A2375

Recents -
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/msf%3A2375

Images-

content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/msf%3A2375

External Storage -

content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Fimages%20.jpeg

Uri working:

content://media/external/images/media/2165

Comment: Adapt existing code. Its no work.

Comment: What do you mean by adapt existing code ? How do I get filepath for different Uris

Comment: I updated the Uri working and not working @blackapps

Comment: Adapt the code to not use a path but an uri. Its very easy and little work.

Comment: @blackapps I need to perform compression as well on the selected image before sending it to server. One way is to create a temp file from Uri inputstream, but this seems inefficient. Do you have any other way ?

Comment: You can do all with that uri. No need to try to get a file system path. Or making a copyfirst.